# Illustrator - Find Lines That Loop Over Themselves

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a scanned and image traced design that I am encoding for our CNC. The last stage is manually fixing some errors. On one document I have a bunch of lines that have inadvertently looped, which causes lots of errors on the CNC. I am having trouble finding all instances of where this has happened.

The problem occurs when the change point tool is used badly. That is the point is changed to have bars, but the mouse is moved the wrong way.

Attached is a photo of the problem zoomed right in and then zoomed out. I've tried using astute graphics vector first aid, but can't find a way to isolate these instances. Anybody got any thoughts?

[image: Zoomed Image]
[image: Wide view]

Comment: Its still potenttially problematic for the cnc mill. Since it has potenttislly full contact but ymmv. Snd this is why some of our cnc operators hate illustrator files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how useful this will be, but it's certainly possible.

If you do a Path Finder Divide operation, then Ungroup <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, it will cut off any loops. Then select the stroke of the object you want to keep, send to the bottom <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, and change the stroke to a different colour. Then you should be able to see the loops. You could then select one of them, and do *Select > Same > Stroke colour*, and delete them.

Of course you may still need to manually fix the corners a bit.

An example

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Works perfectly! Thanks @Billy-Kerr